# process.Start() won't work with Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer

Tags: vb.net

I recently updated my application to use oauth for a swagger interface, which requires opening a webpage to a specific URL and getting the user to authorize access. I then listen for the response sent to the local host and process the access token, etc. To do this I just call process.Start(URL)

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub GetAuthorizationfromWeb()
    Try
        ' Build the authorization call
        Dim URL As String = ESIAuthorizeURL & "?response_type=code" & "&redirect_uri=http://"
        URL &= LocalHost & ":" & LocalPort & "&client_id=" & ClientID & "&scope=" & ScopesString

        Process.Start(URL)

        Dim mySocket As Socket = Nothing
        Dim myStream As NetworkStream = Nothing
        Dim myReader As StreamReader = Nothing
        Dim myWriter As StreamWriter = Nothing

        myListner.Start()

        mySocket = myListner.AcceptSocket() ' Wait for response
        Debug.Print("After socket listen")
        myStream = New NetworkStream(mySocket)
        myReader = New StreamReader(myStream)
        myWriter = New StreamWriter(myStream)
        myWriter.AutoFlush = True

        Do
            AuthStreamText &= myReader.ReadLine & "|"

            If AuthStreamText.Contains("code") Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop Until myReader.EndOfStream

        myWriter.Write("Login Successful!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "You can close this window.")

        myWriter.Close()
        myReader.Close()
        myStream.Close()
        mySocket.Close()
        myListner.Stop()

        Application.DoEvents()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Application.DoEvents()
    End Try

End Sub
```

All of it works fine with Firefox and to some extent Chrome when they are set as the default browser. However, when I try to launch the URL with Edge or Internet Explorer set as my default browser, it just opens a blank web page or the home page. There is no attempt to navigate to the URL set as the argument.

I tried to find another way to do this but basically process.Start seems to be the only option. I'm not going to embed a webbrowser in my code for security reasons.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This [site](http://www.seirer.net/blog/2014/6/10/solved-how-to-open-a-url-in-the-default-browser-in-csharp) shows a technique of probing the registry to determine the default browser's path and using that instead.

Comment: Why not using a `WebBrowser` control instead?

Comment: Because of security. Users need to log in with username and password and I don't want to give the impression I'm scraping their data. The userbase is pretty skittish about anything like that.